# Turn Passata Into Tomato Paste?

Tags: sauce, tomatoes

I have an American recipe that calls for 12oz [Hunts Tomato paste](http://www.hunts.com/products/tomatoes/tomato-paste) and 1.5 cups of water.  The nearest thing I have is [Passata](http://www.tesco.ie/groceries/Product/Details/?id=266724986).

I don't know much about cooking, but they both seem to be made from tomatoes...is there any way I can use the passata I have in place of the tomato paste?  I'm assuming I would reduce the water or completely skip the water - is there a general guideline here?

My instinct is to just throw it in a pot and, if it seems to watery, simmer until it thickens...but I figured I should ask people who know.

Answer (score 2):

Passata is crushed tomato.  Tomato paste is a concentrate of tomato produced by cooking for a long time, removing seeds and skin, and cooking further.  They are different products that are going to produce different results, both flavor-wise and in terms of texture.  If I were you, I would not add extra water at all, if you are going to use the Passata.  I am sure it will be good...it will just be different from the intent of the recipe.

Comment: Also, in my experience, Hunts Tomato Paste has an aggressive level of salt, so it might be necessary to adjust salt levels in your recipe.

Comment: But just to be clear: As Passata is "weaker", substitute tomato paste *and* water by Passata or you would change the total amount of liquid in your recipe. Or use even more and simmer down a bit.

Comment: @Stephie I am not sure I would agree.  Because Passata is a different product the end result is going to be different from the original recipe.  Of course, the original recipe would be helpful, but I would NOT add any water.  Why add water, just to evaporate it off?

Comment: Neither would I add *water*! Perhaps add more *Passata* than the original (paste + water) amount of "liquid" and simmer down to concentrate the flavour and thicken a bit. Sorry if I was unclear in my comment.

Comment: @Stephie ...ahh, got it.